# Cognos 10.2 Prompt API Refresh Cascading Prompt Without Page Refresh

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm trying to find a solution where a user can refresh a prompt without refreshing the whole page.

I have two prompts which cascade:

promptA > promptB

The desired behaviour is

- user makes selection in promptA
- user clicks a link or button to and the report refreshes with the choice(s) from promptA applied [this part is solved]

or

- user clicks a button or link
- report does not refresh
- values for prompt B are displayed
- user clicks link or button to refresh page with choices from promptA and promptB applied

Can anyone suggest anything? Or is this not possible? (I'm aware this is a bit against the grain of a more standard approach such as cascading prompts on an inital prompt page!)

Thanks

Comment: When you say "..without refreshing the whole page.." are  you excluding a reprompt action? I assume you've tried the Auto-Submit property on promptA and/or used a reprompt button.

Comment: Hi, yes that's right. Auto submit isn't appropriate because the user needs to be able to select multiple options from Prompt A. I'm using the reprompt button as the current solution which is workable. I'm just aniticpating users may not want to refresh the results until they've made the decision on values for promptB.

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript but not Cognos JavaScript Prompt API-compliant JavaScript. Cognos' API only supports selecting or deselecting values of an existing value prompt, not adding or removing values. I have built a fully dynamic value prompt using JavaScript in a report but I had to go outside of the supported API to do it. Let me know if you're interested and I'll write it up.

Comment: Hi, yes that would be great - thank you!